# getting values from columns through cursor

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-arrayadapter, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to get values of rows from requested columns using cursor but I am not getting that how to do it,what is the index inside cursor.getLong(?) ,Here is my code it works but I don't how is it working? Please help.

```
private Message cursorToMessage(Cursor cursor) {
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
     message.setmessage(cursor.getString(1));
    message.setthreadid(cursor.getLong(0));
    return message;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the index is the position of the column in your projection of the query.

do if you have in your projection that you want columns `id,message,threadid` then you would do

```
long id = cursor.getLong(0);
String message = cursor.getString(1);
long threadId = cursor.getLong(2);
```

the proper way to get a column so that you dont mix the indexes up would be to do this

```
cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
```

I dont know if you did this or not but you should also be checking if the cursor has anything in it.

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
   message.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
   message.setmessage(cursor.getString(1));
   message.setthreadid(cursor.getLong(0));
}
```

Comment: private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MESSAGE,MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_THREADID };


Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,
        allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
        null, null, null);

Comment: see this is my query in my case indexing would be same as you answered, I have tried but it gives error..!!

Comment: 09-11 06:41:08.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11043): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soft.b.peopleassist/soft.b.peopleassist.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 2 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: did you call `cursor.moveToFirst()` before passing the cursor variable into your method?

Comment: then what about the index of the threadid ,It also has to be the same as the id index?

Comment: so then use `cursor.getLong(0)`

Comment: why to use 0 index for both columns?

Comment: seriously this is basic programming, you have an array of columns you want. just figure out what index the column is that you want and put that number in. thats why I said you should be using `cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("my column from database goes here"));` so you dont have to worry about it